# Cannot access object data when click handler added to google maps circle marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add some text (that is stored within the google maps circle object) to a HTML element when the circle is clicked. The circles have been pushed into an array but when I loop that array to give each circle a click handler the circle object is showing as undefined. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```js
var pickUps = {};
pickUps["wickRailway"] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.441801, -3.097043),
  name: "Wick Railway Station",
};
pickUps["fergusRd"] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.443312, -3.095988),
  name: "St Fergus Road",
};

var map = new GoogleMap();
map.initialize();

var pickUpCircle;

function GoogleMap() {

  this.initialize = function() {
    var map = showMap();
  }

  var showMap = function() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      streetViewControl: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.441245, -3.094398),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var circlesArray = [];

    for (var pickUp in pickUps) {

      var pickUpOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        clickable: true,
        map: map,
        center: pickUps[pickUp].center,
        radius: 10,
        pickUpName: pickUps[pickUp].name
      };
      pickUpCircle = new google.maps.Circle(pickUpOptions);
      circlesArray.push(pickUpCircle);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < circlesArray.length; i++) {

      //circlesArray[i] works here

      google.maps.event.addListener(circlesArray[i], 'click', function() {

        //circlesArray[i] is undefined here

      });
    };
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: When the loop ends `i` is equal to `circlesArray.length`, one past the end of the array.  This problem is typically solved with function closure (for marker infoWindows)

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you do the following instead

```
for (var i = 0; i < circlesArray.length; i++) {

  //circlesArray[i] works here
  var circ = circlesArray[i];
  google.maps.event.addListener(circ, 'click', function() {

    //circlesArray[i] is undefined 
    //what is circ here?

  });
};
```

Comment: That worked better than before, but when both circles were clicked it only showed the data for the last one in the array. However, I changed your answer slightly and got it to work by moving the click handler into a separate function and calling that with circ. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, the issue is that the variable i does not exist when the listener function is invoked. Hence why I suggested it that way. Glad you tailored it to suit your needs.